# How to use Airflow ExternalTaskSensor as a SmartSensor?

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to implement the ExternalTaskSensor using SmartSensors but since it uses `execution_date` to poke for the other DAG status I can't seem to be able to pass it, if I omit it from my SmartExternalSensor it says that there is a `KeyError` with the execution_date, since it doesn't exist.

I tried overriding the `get_poke_context` method

```
    def get_poke_context(self, context):
        result = super().get_poke_context(context)

        if self.execution_date is None:
            result['execution_date'] = context['execution_date']

        return result
```

but It now says that the datetime object is not json serializable (this is done while registering the sensor as a SmartSensor using json.dumps) and runs as a normal sensor. If I pass directly the string of that datetime object it says that `str object has no isoformat() method` so I know the execution date must be a datetime object.

Do you guys have any idea on how to work around this?

Comment: how about converting your string to DateTime object before use as execution date?

Comment: @KaBoom I get the error `datetime object is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 1):

I get similar issues trying to use ExternalTaskSensor as a SmartSensor. This below hasn't been tested extensively, but seems to work.

```py
import datetime

from airflow.sensors.external_task import ExternalTaskSensor
from airflow.utils.session import provide_session


class SmartExternalTaskSensor(ExternalTaskSensor):
    # Something a bit odd happens with ExternalTaskSensor when run as a smart
    # sensor. ExternalTaskSensor requires execution_date in the poke context,
    # but the smart sensor system passes all poke context values to the
    # constructor of ExternalTaskSensor, but it doesn't allow execution_date
    # as an argument. So we add it...
    def __init__(self, execution_date=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_poke_context(self, context):
        return {
            'external_dag_id': self.external_dag_id,
            'external_task_id': self.external_task_id,
            'timeout': self.timeout,
            'check_existence': self.check_existence,
            # ... but execution_date has to be manually extracted from the
            # context, and converted to a string, since it will be JSON
            # encoded by the smart sensor system...
            'execution_date': context['execution_date'].isoformat(),
        }

    @provide_session
    def poke(self, context, session=None):
        return super().poke(
            {
                **context,
                # ... and then converted back to a datetime object since
                # that's what ExternalTaskSensor poke needs
                'execution_date': datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(
                    context['execution_date']
                ),
            },
            session,
        )
```